# How to separate and position ID variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, time

I have an ID named TIMZ I am trying to position each of my digital times in this ID separately but instead they are all conjoined. I partially understand this is due to the style but how I would I correct my code so that I can position each TimZ separately instead of being together as they are showed in the image. Thanks!

Image of TIMZ ID and what does:[image]

HTML CODE FOR ID:

```
<div id="timZ" class="row" style="width: 90%;">

</div>
<script>
    // window.localStorage.removeItem('time');
    var s=window.localStorage.getItem('time');
    var s=JSON.parse(s);
    // console.log(s);
    s.forEach(function(time, index) {
        $('<div/>', {
            "class": 'timZonM col',
            'data-timezone': `${time.offset}`,
        }).appendTo('#timZ');
```

CSS Code:

```
div.timZonM { /* military time */
/*  width: 3em;  */
/*  margin:.3em; */
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid crimson;
  font-size: 110px;
  font-family: 'Monserrat';
 /* letter-spacing: .05em; */
}
div.timZonM::after {
  content: attr(data-seconds);
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: `timZonM` is a div with default display:block. How is it showing side-by-side? Please share a simple demo for this and hard-code values for `s` variable also.

Comment: In all major browsers you can right click on the number and select "Inspect" (or a similarly named menu item) to see what CSS rules apply to it and where they come from. It doesn't make much sense to fight your own styling with code changes.

Comment: @palaѕн It is showing side by side because of the class="row" that I put in. If I did not put this class they would show up one on top of the other, but I want the free will to position each one wherever I want but am not sure how

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Correct, I added class row so that they will no longer stack on top of one another which they did without this class. I want the. option to position each block but am not sure how and the closet I was able to get was by doing class row

Comment: Neither `row` nor any other class name has any effect on styling by default. You must have some CSS (either custom or framework driven) to accomplish that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Okay, I understand this is my current css for this ID 
div.timZonM { /* military time */
/*  width: 3em;  */
/*  margin:.3em; */
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid crimson;
  font-size: 110px;
  font-family: 'Monserrat';
 /* letter-spacing: .05em; */
}
div.timZonM::after {
  content: attr(data-seconds);
  color:white;
}

Comment: Please share a simple demo for this and hard-code values for s variable also, so that others could debug and help.

Comment: @palaѕн Okay, thanks

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález its a bit confusing so give me a little time so I can edit my code so it shows better